# PHP, MySQL: Need to show Parent name only once.. almost there but still a problem

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, grouping

I have a parent category that holds all Cars names, denoted by parent_name in table "parent". For each of these parents, there could be any number of car models & they all go in table called "model". Each of these models can have any number of images & refereced via the model_id as the Foreign Key. My task is to show all the Parent Name only once (as in a group) and at the same time, list all the models under that Parent with just 1 corresponding image. The parent_name should not be shown more than once.

**MY EXPERIMENTS:**

I basically tried to write 2 queries. One was to left join "parent" table on "models" & use GROUP BY parent_id and then in the while loop, write another query to fetch only 1 image using by joining the models & images tables by using model_id field. But doing this lists only 1 Model, even though there are multiple models. So I tried to use GROUP BY parent_id, model_id. Using this does show all the models but at the same time, also repeats showing the parent_name & I need the parent_name to show only once throughout the page. You can say that I am trying to GROUP the model_name under the parent & show all the models under a single parent and I am showing only 1 image of the model. If somehow I can avoid showing the parent_name multiple times, the issue would be solved.

**Following are my table schemas:**

```
//Table parent

parent_id   parent_name
    1        Par1
    2       Par2


//Table model

model_id    parent_id   model_name
    1            1       Model1
    2           2       Model2
    3           1       Model3
    4           1       Model4
    5            2       Model5

//Table model_images

image_id    model_id
    1            1
    2           1
    3           1
    4            2
    5           3
    6           3
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
Par1    ---> This is the parent. Needs to be shown only once.
Model1  -->  This is a model. List all models that belong to this parent. 
image_id 1 -> Show only 1 image of the model (model may have multiple images but I need just one) 

Model3  -->  This is a model.
image_id 5  -> Show only 1 image of the model    

Model4  -->  This is a model.
No Image    -> Note that no image exists for this model. So we show "No Image" text.

------------------------------------------------------------

Par2    ---> This is the parent. Needs to be shown only once.
Model2  -->  This is a model.
image_id 4  -> Show only 1 image of the model

Model5  -->  This is a model.
No Image   -> Note that no image exists for this model. So we show "No Image" text.
```

I need the PHP & mySQL code to achieve the above. All help in resolving the issue is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT 1:**
Sorry, I forgot to add this. I am non-object oriented programmer. So I would really be thankful if you can avoid object oriented code in your solution and show me the same in a non-oops way. Thanks.

Comment: From what I read in the first paragraph, I don't understand why want to show parent_name only once (which I interpret as only one row should be shown). I'm sure you use mysql's array_accum aggregate (or whatever it's called) to group all the models of a parent under one column and one image for each model in another column, but it's not that advantageous. As to the rest -- tl;dr, but if you want a SQL query, you should show your desired output in a tabular form.

Comment: @Artefacto Thank you for the response. Why I want to show it just once is that I am trying to Group all the models under a Parent. So if 100 models share 10 Parents at the rate of 10 Models/Parent, then instead of showing the name of the Parent 100 times (because we have 100 Models), I just want to show the name of each Parent only once & show the 10 Models corresponding to this Parent under it. I really don't care if this needs to be shown in a table or a div based layout. I just need output. I am almost there  with the exception that the Parent name keeps repeating & I need to avoid that.

Comment: OK I understand now you don't necessarily want to do this redundancy cut in SQL only. Kau-Boy's answer looks good then. It will still fetch the 100 rows, but then it will group them under a PHP array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do it in one query and than combine it to an associative array:

```
$query = '  SELECT     *
            FROM       parent AS p
            LEFT JOIN  model AS m
            ON         p.id = m.parent_id
            LEFT JOIN  model_images AS m_i
            ON         m.model_id = m_i.model_id';

$array = array();

if($mysli->query($quer)){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $array[$row['parent_name']][$row['model_id']] = $row;
    }
}
```

You will than have an associative array with the parent name as the key of the array. You can then use a for loop to print the key only once (with $i = 0) but the rest value by value.

Is that clear enough?

**EDIT**: Your array than might look like this:

```
Array(
  'Par 1' => 
    Array(
      [0] => Array(
        'parent_id' => 1,
        'parent_name' => 'Par 1',
        'model_id' => 1,
        'model_name' => 'Model 1',
        'image_id',
      ),
      [1] => Array(...)
    ),
    'Par 2' => Array(...)
)
```

So to print out you need two loops. One for the parents (and there names) and one for their childs (models in this case).

```
foreach($array as $par_name => $models){
    echo 'Parent name: '.$par_name.'<br />';
    echo 'Model ID: '.$models[0]['model_id'].', Model Name: '.$models[0]['name']; // replace with your desired output
}
```

Now an idea of how it works? An sure as Artefacto said, you can use procedural functions if you don't like OOP functions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry, I don't understand the code that you have provided(& it's due to my lack of understanding of OOPS based programming). I edited my question as well to reflect the same. Could you please show me the same in a non OOP way?

Comment: @Denver If you don't want to use OOP, just use `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of the method calls.

Comment: @Artefacto I posted the response in the comment below. Kindly check it out.